# How do I write a custom search provider for Windows Explorer search UI

Tags: windows, search, explorer, windows-search, virtualfilesystem

I am working on a Windows Explorer Namespace Extension which is a virtual filesystem. With regards to this, I would like to support search from the search dialog available in Windows Explorer.

Currently I'm able to search by name in the folder I'm standing in, but I would like to be able to search in the complete structure and also within content of the virtual filesystem, and since Windows Explorer cannot do this, I need to hook in a custom search provider.

Since it is a virtual filesystem, it would be beneficial if I could write a custom UI for displaying the result, but this isn't mandatory.

The custom Explorer namespace extension is written in C#, but the API doesn't need to be wrapped. Any pointers to API documentation, commercial products and/or samples would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to drop one of your tags and specify which programming language you hope to accomplish this in. Good Luck.

Comment: The programming language isn't the important point. I haven't found any API for this - regardless of language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using defview as your shell view, return FWF_USESEARCHFOLDER in IFolderViewSettings::GetFolderFlags. Sample implementation can be found at http://regnamespace.codeplex.com/.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331575(v=vs.85).aspx :
If your IShellFolder implementation does not use SHCreateShellFolderView to create the DefView, the Shell view object may need IFolderView.

[There is also confused user who need to support shell namespace extension folder searching in file dialogs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/windowssearch/thread/f1ab208f-a367-4f4a-af49-fb5af99ec54f).